# select list of columns dynamically in MySQL

Tags: mysql, select, stored-procedures, execute, dynamic-columns

I've looked through a lot of posts on this site and others and I can't figure this out. I'm trying to select a list of columns from a table and then use them in a query similar to this:

```
set @cols = (select group_concat(column_name) as 'col_list' FROM `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.`COLUMNS` WHERE (`TABLE_SCHEMA` = 'REPORTS' AND `TABLE_NAME` = 't_labor' AND column_name like '%host%'));

set @s = 'select ' + @cols + ' from REPORTS.t_labor';

prepare stmt from @s;
execute stmt;
deallocate prepare stmt;

-- execute ('select ' + @cols + ' from REPORTS.t_sales');
```

I am trying to run the above statements as-is. I also tried creating a stored procedure, but I have never worked with stored procedures in MySQL before and I don't know how to debug them. I would prefer to do this without using a stored procedure if possible, but if it's necessary that's ok.

I tried using the **prepare** statement, and I tried the **execute** statement but I couldn't get either to work.

Answer (score 1):

Wild guess here, but try this.

```
set @cols = (select group_concat(column_name) as 'col_list' FROM `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.`COLUMNS` WHERE (`TABLE_SCHEMA` = 'REPORTS' AND `TABLE_NAME` = 't_labor' AND column_name like '%host%'));

PREPARE stmt1 FROM 'select ? from REPORTS.t_labor';

EXECUTE stmt1 USING @cols;

DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt1;
```

Comment: I ran that and it returned the list of column names for each row of the result set, not the actual data. But I think we have to be close.

Answer (score 1):

Finally figured it out:

```
    set @cols = (select group_concat(column_name) as 'col_list' FROM `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.`COLUMNS` WHERE (`TABLE_SCHEMA` = 'REPORTS' AND `TABLE_NAME` = 't_labor' AND column_name like '%host%'));

set @qry = concat('select ', @cols, ' from REPORTS.t_labor');

PREPARE stmt1 FROM @qry;

EXECUTE stmt1;

DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt1;
```

Had to piece together replies from at least 5 different posts similar to this question plus Dr OSWaldo's reply.

Comment: glad you made it ;-)